# s => s == 'w' - Help me understand this line of code

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and coding in general and have a question on one exercise I'm doing. I am following the exercises on w3resource and I came across a challenge where I have to solve this: 
"Write a C# program to check if a given string contains 'w' character between 1 and 3 times."

My solution was this:

```
    var theString = Console.ReadLine(); 
    var theArray = theString.ToCharArray();
    int betweenOneAndThree = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < theArray.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (theArray[i] == 'w')
                betweenOneAndThree++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(betweenOneAndThree >= 1 && betweenOneAndThree <= 3);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

This worked just fine, but I checked their solution and it goes like this:

```
Console.Write("Input a string (contains at least one 'w' char) : ");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            var count = str.Count(s => s == 'w');
            Console.WriteLine("Test the string contains 'w' character  between 1 and 3 times: ");
            Console.WriteLine(count >= 1 && count <= 3);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I can't see `'s'` being declared as a char variable and I do not understand what it does here. Can anyone please explain to me what `s => s == 'w'` does?

Yes, I have tried googling this. But I can't seem to find an answer.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The term you should google for is `c# lambda expressions`

Comment: [Lambda Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) also [IEnumerable.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It is an anonymous function that takes one parameter `s` and checks equality against `'w'`

Comment: It reads: 'an item s from the set goes to a bool that compares it to x'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).

In this case it declares an [anonymous delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods) which is passed to Count, whose signature for [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) specifies a `Func<T, bool>` which is a typed representation of an anonymous function which takes a T (the type of the object in the collection) and returns bool. `Count()` here will execute this function against each object in the collection, and count how many times it returned `true`.

Answer (score 1):

`str.Count(s => s == 'w')` is basically a shortened way to say this:

```
result = 0;
foreach (char s in str)
{
    if (s == 'w')
    {
        result += 1;
    }
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

`s => s == 'w'` is Predicate delegate with lambda expression,

`str.Count(s => s == 'w')` simply counts the occurences of the characters `w`